# How can I prevent icon alignment changes when ImageButton background is hidden?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-actionbar, imagebutton, android-spinner

I have an ImageButton in my application's Action Bar that I use to simulate a spinner for changing views by selecting the title (I'm using MonoDroid.ActionBar as a starting point - http://bit.ly/UBzI77).

[image: ImageButton-Before]

Here's the XML for the ImageButton.

```
 <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/title_spinner_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionbar_title"/>
```

When I make the ImageButton background transparent by adding an android:background attribute to the XML.

```
 <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/title_spinner_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionbar_title" 
      android:background="@null"/>
```

The ImageButton background disappears but the icon is centered vertically.

[image: ImageButton-After]

Does anyone know how to make the ImageButton background transparent but keep the icon aligned at the bottom of the ImageButton?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you played with `android:scaleType`? Something like: `android:scaleType="matrix"`. Options are MATRIX, FIT_START, FIT_END, etc. [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in combination with your null background:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" // this is here just to ensure the image doesn't sit flush against the bottom of the bar, vary as required
```

Alternatively, you could try

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: Xono - Your android:layout_height/android:gravity suggestion worked. Thanks!

Comment: Xono - The android:layout_alignParentBottom/android:layout_marginBottom combination does put the icon at the bottom of the ImageButton but no matter what you set the marginBottom to the icon doesn't move from its  initial position.

Comment: Really? It should have worked - in fact, I was sort of expecting the first to work and the second to break, not the opposite. It seems RelativeLayout's alignParent and margins don't play nice together. Could try replacing the marginBottom with `android:paddingBottom="3dp"`, see if that works any better.